# Subsetting a data.table using another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have the `dt` and `dt1` `data.table`s.

```
dt<-data.table(id=c(rep(2, 3), rep(4, 2)), year=c(2005:2007, 2005:2006), event=c(1,0,0,0,1))
dt1<-data.table(id=rep(2, 5), year=c(2005:2009), performance=(1000:1004))

dt

   id year event
1:  2 2005     1
2:  2 2006     0
3:  2 2007     0
4:  4 2005     0
5:  4 2006     1

dt1

   id year performance
1:  2 2005        1000
2:  2 2006        1001
3:  2 2007        1002
4:  2 2008        1003
5:  2 2009        1004
```

I would like to subset the former using the combination of its first and second column that also appear in `dt1`. As a result of this, I would like to create a new object without overwriting `dt`. This is what I'd like to obtain.

```
   id year event
1:  2 2005     1
2:  2 2006     0
3:  2 2007     0
```

I tried to do this using the following code:

```
dt.sub<-dt[dt[,c(1:2)] %in% dt1[,c(1:2)],]
```

but it didn't work. As a result, I got back a data table identical to `dt`. I think there are at least two mistakes in my code. The first is that I am probably subsetting the `data.table` by column using a wrong method. The second, and pretty evident, is that `%in%` applies to vectors and not to multiple-column objects. Nevertherless, I am unable to find a more efficient way to do it...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setkeyv(dt,c('id','year'))
setkeyv(dt1,c('id','year'))
dt[dt1,nomatch=0]
```

Output -

```
> dt[dt1,nomatch=0]
   id year event performance
1:  2 2005     1        1000
2:  2 2006     0        1001
3:  2 2007     0        1002
```

Comment: Many thanks! Probably this one is faster in very big `data.table`s.

Comment: If you don't want the `performance` column, then doing `dt[dt1, list(event), nomatch=0L]` should be a tad faster...

Comment: `data.table` supplies its own `merge` method, which works along these lines. I would expect the speed to be similar.

Comment: @James, at the moment, `left`, `right` and `inner` joins are quite fast (if not the fastest). However, `outer` join (`merge(..., all=TRUE)` seems to have some improvements possible).

Comment: `?merge` already mentions that `X[Y ...]` is faster than `merge`, however it's not *that* slow (especially for the task in this question).

Comment: @Arun Thank you so much. I was also looking for that.

Comment: Sure, just so you know, for your question, Codoremifa's seems more the data.table way to me (personal opinion of course).

Comment: @Arun Probably you're right and, for everybody's benefit, I should change and accept that one. But isn't that directly updating dt instead of creating a new object? Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @Riccardo, no, as long as you don't use `:=`, there's no update by reference happening. You can just try it out yourself. Do `ans <- dt[dt1, list(event), nomatch=0L]` and check `ans`, `dt` and `dt1`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `merge`:

```
merge(dt,dt1, by=c("year","id"))
   year id event performance
1: 2005  2     1        1000
2: 2006  2     0        1001
3: 2007  2     0        1002
```

Comment: OMG, sometimes the solution it's so easy that you can't see it... Thanks
!